# Make callback method accessible to google maps

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a html script line

```html
<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"
      async defer>
</script>
```

which have a callback method called `initMap()` that reside in my `main.js` file. Now I'm trying to adopt the use of modules, so I have added `type=module` to my script line.

```html
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Now the browser is complaining that there is no `initMap` function. I have tried to add `export` in front of the function declaration for `initMap()` but it doesn't work. How do I expose `initMap()` to the API callback? Also, why is the method `initMap()` becomes in accessible after adding `type=module`? I'm new to using modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; Before adding `type="module"` the `initMap` was in the global scope (i.e. on the `window` object) so when the Google Maps script has finished loading it said "Hey runtime! Execute a function with name 'initMap' for me" and engine went looking for it in the current scope, found the `initMap` and executed it.

Modules are all about the encapsulation though so everything inside them is private unless exported (which is a direction you've already started exploring).
However exporting is just the half of the solution - you also need to import that function.
I work mostly in codebases where you do bundling with webpack and there you typically export bunch of stuff in your modules and then import them like so: `import { myFunction } from "./path/to/module.js"`.
I don't see how you could use that in this `<script>`-in-HTML setup though so instead of that you could add the `initMap` to the `window` object manually, so that the runtime finds it when Google Maps request it.

```js
// inside main.js
function initMap() {
  console.log("Hey! This is inside a callback passed to Google Maps script");
}

// this is IIFE - i.e. runs immediately
(function() {
  window.initMap = initMap;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's very helpful. I have solved the problem by just searching through some other old google documentation and found this `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap)`. So I just removed the callback argument from the script src. Still I think your explanation clarifies a lot. Thanks!

Comment: One more question though. Why would one use IIFE instead of just writing out the contents within the function?

Comment: No problem, your solution looks cleaner so definitely go with that. Good observation with the IIFE being unnecessary. It should work the same. I prefer the IIFE version just because I find it to be more explicit about the side-effect (modifying the `window` object).